# LaTeX to pdf; printing

Tags: pdftex, printing

This might be off-topic, since it appears to be a printer problem, but I wondered if anyone else has encountered this.

When I generate a pfd document from a LaTeX source using Pdftex in TeXShop 3.56, it displays just fine on my OSX machine and will print without problems on an older laser printer. On a printer we just bought, though, it appears that the default font has been replaced with a courier-like mess with what I can only call schizophrenic kerning. As an additional data point, any "ff"s that are in the document are replaced with whitespace. Has this happened to anyone else? I sure hope so, and that there's a fix.

Comment: Try printing from a different pdf viewer, e.g. Foxit, Sumatra, Acrobat Reader, etc.  This might help you identify the problem location.

Comment: Does this only happen with pdftex generated documents? Can you print from other apps (eg: Office)? Can you print other pdflatex generated documents downloaded from internet (eg: any ctan manual)?

Comment: @JLDiaz. I just tried all three of your tests. (1) yes, as far as I know, (2) yes, (3) interestingly, no. When I download and print some ctan manuals, the result is generally a blank page, though I do get some boxes and vertical lines but no text whatsoever.

Comment: @R.Schumacher. Prints just fine from Acrobat Reader.

Comment: *it appears that the default font has been replaced with a courier-like mess with what I can only call schizophrenic kerning.* :-D

Comment: This can happen when the fonts aren't embedded in the PDF file generated. Usually going to Properties in the PDF viewer software will show a list of embedded fonts; if the font you used (typically Computer Modern or Latin Modern) isn't listed it means pdftex failed to embed the font.